# Keeping the first row of a tableview constant

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, scroll

I am trying to display data in a UITableView, and the first row will be a label to identify the type of data. How can I keep the first row as a label when scrolling down?

Thanks!

Comment: tableviewheader for section u needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the TableView header. Here is an example:

```
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)];
headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"blablabla", @"");
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[header addSubview:headerLabel];

    myTable.tableHeaderView = header;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the header's of table views to do this specifically. All the functionality is already built into the UITableView class. In the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource), just implement

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way you can implement it is by using the `tableHeaderView` property of the `UITableView`. Make the `tableHeaderView` look like the first row of your table and begin the table from the 2nd row.